How to combine lighting while maintaining vibrant texture colours with toon shaders
I’m very new to creating materials in Blender and I’m trying an adaptive cel-shaded shader which allows me to change out material textures inspired by Borderlands 2 aesthetic.
I’m wondering if it’s possible to combine the lighting and hatching styles while also maintaining the colours of the materials?
From my limited knowledge, I believe the issue is with how I set up the texture by separating the RGB to create a 3-point lighting scene. The colours of the stylised materials are tied to these lights (which I don’t want), as this doesn’t allow for any room for changing the colour of the surrounding lights. The other extreme removes all of the vibrant colours and details out of the texture image to achieve the neon lighting and hatching.
Vibrant materials, but no neon lighting and hatching details:

Neon lighting and hatching details, but no material colours and minimal details:

Both this image and the one above use a marble texture seen in the first image in the top right
Separate RGB Node used for 3-point light:

Blender File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G34Ka-BzVFS3-j5UVxLtlGMTIOGUfG6V/view
Thanks
